# When one's stockings tears

Tags: word-request, verbs, idioms

Which verb/idiom is normally used to describe this happening?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGxq1.jpg)

- Her stickings has torn (or what?)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Stockings** are plural. As a result, the following are suitable:

> Her stockings tear.
>
> Her stockings have torn.
>
> She has torn her stockings.

At least in the UK (English speakers elsewhere might chip in), you also might hear the noun or verb **ladder**; imagine the shape of a ladder in torn stockings.

> She's laddered her stockings.
>
> She has a ladder in her stockings.

Edit: Thanks to Mike Harris in the comments:

> She has a run in her stockings.

Comment: The US term is _run_ rather than _ladder._ I don't think it's ever used as a verb, strictly as "she has a run in her stockings."

Comment: @MikeHarris Thanks! Added to the answer :-)

Comment: Yes @Mike Harris! I have read run and ladder, but I couldn't distinguish between them! Many thanks for pointing that out.